# Matlab - Drawing 3D figure in real time

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a 3D cylinder showing in Matlab that updates in real time, it's supposed to swap frames(images) as the value of the loop increases.
<s>My problem however is that instead of keeping the frames within figure it opens up a new figure for every frame.</s>

I can't use the custom colormap that I've loaded in either(which is why I'm using parula at the moment) and another problem that I have is that I can't get figures to open in the live editor, I have to use the command window. Wondering if someone might see what I'm missing here, thanks in advance!

My code.

```matlab
clc;
clear all;
close all;

filename = ['*The file pathway*' 'filenames.txt'];
T = readtable(filename);
tsize = size(T);
tsize (1);

filename = strcat('*The file pathway*', string(T{350,1}));
heat = double(getHeatMap(filename));

load('newColorMap.mat');

for i = 1:tsize
    filename = strcat('*The file pathway*', string(T{i,1}));
    heat = double(getHeatMap(filename));
    [X,tY] = meshgrid( linspace(1,400,size(heat,2)),linspace(0,2*pi,size(heat,1)));
    max_heat = max(heat, [], 'all');
    min_heat = min(heat, [], 'all');
    R = (((heat-min_heat)/(max_heat-min_heat))*50)+100;
    Y = cos(tY) .* R;
    Z = sin(tY) .* R;
    [nx, ny, nz] = surfnorm(X,Y,Z);
    nv = reshape([nx ny nz], size(nx,1),size(nx,2),3);
    CV = R;
    figure
    s = surf(X,Y,Z,heat,'VertexNormals',nv, 'EdgeColor','none');
    axis([0 400 -200 200 -200 200])
    colorbar
    colormap('parula')
    lighting gouraud
    camlight
    material dull
    caxis([0 80])
    drawnow
end
```

```matlab
function heat = getCylinderHeatMap(filename)
    %Returns a struct with info about the file.
    s = dir(filename);
    %Opens a file for reading, hence the 'r'.
    fin = fopen(filename,'r');
    I=fread(fin,s.bytes,'uint8=>uint8');
    
    w = uint16(I(1))+256*uint16(I(2));
    h = uint16(I(3))+256*uint16(I(4));
    skip = s.bytes - w*h + 1;
    IN = I(skip:1:s.bytes);
    Z=single(reshape(IN,w,h));
    Z=griddedInterpolant(Z');
    y_range = linspace(1.0,single(h),360);
    x_range = linspace(1.0,single(w),512);
    heat = uint8(Z({y_range, x_range}));
end
```

Comment: You’re creating a new `figure` each time through the loop. That’s why each frame shows in a separate figure.

Comment: I got it to work by keeping figure outside of the loop. Now I still have the problem of not being able to load and use the colormapeditor made newColorMap.mat and I can't create a figure in a new window when using live editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beaker I managed to keep the frames within the figure by keeping the figure command outside of the loop.

I managed to solve the other two problems on my own by adding the commando set(gcf,'Visible','on') after figure to show it in a separate window from the live editor and I managed to add the custom colormap by using lowercase letter instead of using camelcase like in the filename newColorCamp.mat.